# Выделение текущего пункта меню на CSS

Tags: html, css

Начал делать меню на сайте, и столкнулся с проблемой, не могу понять, как посредством CSS можно выделить категорию меню в которой я сейчас нахожусь, к примеру, есть такой код меню:

```
  <ul class="h-nav">
            <li><a href="/"class="is-active">главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="/kriminal">правовая база</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">истории из жизни</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">новости</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.h-nav {height: 40px; background-color: #f3f3f3; border-bottom: 2px solid #1070b9;}
.h-nav li {display: inline-block;}
.h-nav a {display: block; padding: 0 20px; line-height: 40px; text-transform: uppercase; font-size:12px;}
.h-nav a:hover, .h-nav a.is-active {color: #fff; background: radial-gradient( #3daee7, #1070b9);}
```

Получается, что когда пользователь на главной, надпись в меню "Главная" выделена синим цветом, остальные пункты меняют цвет только при наведении курсором, вопрос состоит в том, как сделать, чтоб при переходе в другую категорию она становилась активной(выделялась синим) в то время как "главная" приобретала свой первостепенный вид? Я просмотрел кучу информации по этому поводу, и все предлагают реализацию посредством JS, что мне не подходит, существует ли решение на CSS?

Comment: если только на css о создаёте сколько угодно страниц , в css создаёте для тега `a` class:special;  и на каждой странице к определённому пункту присваиваете этот class в которо будет написано что ссылка имеет серобуромалиновый цвет а все остальные у нас дефолт

Comment: Максим Ленский, не совсем уловил ход Ваших мыслей, так как меню находится в шапке сайта, внутри <header> и сама страница меняется при переходе в категорию, но header остается без изменений, какие страницы я должен создавать?

Comment: я понимаю где оно находится - но активная вкладка делается либо на php либо на js .... если хотите на css о метод я описал уже

Comment: Понятно,  спасибо

Comment: вам что то не ясно ? может помочь ?

Comment: Вам все верно ответили. Если сайт динамичный, то в помощь только PHP или JS. Если статичный, то ручками в пунктах меню прописывайте `class="is-active"` для текущей страницы.

Comment: Я понимаю что мне верно ответили, и поблагодарил Максима, у меня сайт на DLE и я не вижу в стилях или в tpl файлах указание на описание страниц с категориями, сами категории создаются в админпанели, и я понял что при помощи только CSS не получится реализовать это, значит сделаю меню чуть по другому, еще раз спасибо за подсказку

Comment: Почитал еще раз документацию DLE, получилось это сделать как Вы говорили + при помощи тегов видимости [aviable=раздел] [/aviable] и [category=X] [/category]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выглядит все примерно так:

```
[not-category=1-5]
         <ul class="h-nav ">
                <li><a href="/"class="is-active">главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="/kriminal">правовая база</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">истории из жизни</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">новости</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">контакты</a></li>
            </ul> 
      [/not-category]
              [category=5]
                       <ul class="h-nav ">
                <li><a href="/">главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="/kriminal"class="is-active">правовая база</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">истории из жизни</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">новости</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
                [/category]

        [category=4]
                       <ul class="h-nav ">
                <li><a href="/">главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="/kriminal">правовая база</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="is-active">истории из жизни</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">новости</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
                [/category]
```

и так все 5, благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 0):

На CSS такое вряд ли сделаешь, поэтому и используют js, который смотрит текущий адрес страницы и подсвечивает нужный элемент списка. Но, если у вас код формируется через php, то можно сделать аналогично, чтобы при формировании меню автоматом прописывался класс is-active для текущей страницы.